# CppCMS tutorial: Linking template statically error (controller issue)

Tags: c++, cppcms

From http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_hello_templates#The.controller

I've places below codes on bottom of `hello.cpp`:

```
virtual void main(std::string /*url*/)
{
    content::message c;
    c.text=">>>Hello<<<";
    render("message",c);
}
```

When running `g++ hello.cpp my_skin.cpp -o hello -lcppcms -lbooster`, got error:

```
hello.cpp:44:38: error: ‘virtual’ outside class declaration
hello.cpp:44:38: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’
hello.cpp:44:14: warning: first argument of ‘int main(std::string)’ should be ‘int’ [-Wmain]
hello.cpp:44:14: warning: ‘int main(std::string)’ takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main(std::string)’:
hello.cpp:44:38: error: declaration of C function ‘int main(std::string)’ conflicts with
hello.cpp:27:5: error: previous declaration ‘int main(int, char**)’ here
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main(std::string)’:
hello.cpp:48:23: error: ‘render’ was not declared in this scope
```

Do I missed something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages are telling you everything you need to know.

1. `virtual` can only be used in a class. Your main method is not in a class.
2. The `main` method must return an `int`. Yours is returning `void`.
3. You have two main methods, one that is `main(std::string)` and one that is `main(int, char**)`
4. Your render method must have a function prototype above the main method or the entire method needs to me moved.

So this would be more appropriate:

```
void render(std::string, std::string) // or whatever
{
   // do something
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   render("string", c);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hello.cpp should look like below:

```
#include <cppcms/application.h>
#include <cppcms/applications_pool.h>
#include <cppcms/service.h>
#include <cppcms/http_response.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "content.h"

class hello : public cppcms::application {
public:
    hello(cppcms::service &srv) : cppcms::application(srv) {}
    virtual void main(std::string url);
};

void hello::main(std::string /*url*/){
    content::message cc;
    cc.text=">>>Hello<<<";
    render("message", cc);
}

int main(int argc,char ** argv){
    try {
        cppcms::service srv(argc,argv);
        srv.applications_pool().mount(cppcms::applications_factory<hello>());
        srv.run();
    }
    catch(std::exception const &e) {
        std::cerr<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```